# How can I get posts from 9/13/11 to today with SQL?

Tags: posts, sql, phpmyadmin

I have been working with a client to redesign his site and we are at the stage where we are going live, except I'm running into a little problem. Time is of the essence, as the deadline is mid-day tomorrow.

Since I began working on the site, he sent me a database of posts from the beginning of time up until September 13, 2011. Now that we're going live with the new design, I need to update the posts in the new database from that day up until today so they don't get lost in the process.

I tried using WordPress' export feature, unfortunately there are far too many posts for it to allow me to even download the file. So what I want to do is use an SQL query to get these posts, and export a `.sql` file in phpMyAdmin.

Can anybody give me an example of how I would do this? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Questions on this site should be about WordPress or WordPress administration.  Generic SQL questions are better suited for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]